# How to get return value of method into <link> element in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to add ticks of modification date of CSS file to the link.

I wrote some code that returns the ticks of modification date:

```
protected string GetFoundationCssModifiedDateTicks()
{
    var cssPath = Server.MapPath("~/css") + "\\" + "foundation.min.css";
    return GetFileModifiedDateTicks(cssPath).ToString();
}

private long GetFileModifiedDateTicks(string fileName)
{
    return !File.Exists(fileName) ? 0 : File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName).Ticks;
}
```

changed declaration of CSS file in ASPX page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.min.css?<%= GetFoundationCssModifiedDateTicks() %>"/>
```

But it doesn't work and returns the following to browser:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.min.css?&lt;%= GetFoundationCssModifiedDateTicks() %>" />
```

Comment: Try giving the absolute path, no the relative path

Comment: Absolute path of what?

Comment: the path of 'foundation.min.css'. Also check the folder access permissions.